# Series of the reciprocal of the difference of two squares

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I proceed in finding an expression for the following $$S=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\,.$$
Using partial fraction decomposition -- which I imagine is the expected way to go about it because of how it is written -- I get
$$\frac{1}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{4}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\frac{4}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\, ,$$
but I don't know how to progress from here. The expression makes it appear like $S$ might be a telescoping series but I'm not sure how to "change" the $1/2$ into just $1$ by rearranging, the closest I get is
$$4\left(\frac{1}{1/2\left(2n-1\right)}-\frac{1}{1/2\left(2n+1\right)}\right)\,.$$

The only similar questions on the site have an integer in place of $1/2$ or are proofs of generalisations of this problem, which use maths beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mathematical expression can be rearranged as follows:
$$8\left[\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(2n+1\right)}\right]$$
which is, no doubt, a *telescoping series*.

Comment: Note the OP's statement of $\frac{1}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{4}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\frac{4}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$ should be $\frac{1}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$ instead. Thus, your $8$ should be $2$ instead. FYI, a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4102819/602049) was just asked a short while ago.