# Sum of the series $\sum^{∞}_{n = 1} \frac{1}{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum^{∞}_{n = 1} \frac{1}{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)}$$

This series does not look like a power series, and I also tried using partial fraction integration which did not work. I also can't think of a known function that has similar terms. Is there another method for finding the sum of a series?

Comment: Hint:Cant we do a partial sum and see this through? $1/2\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$

Comment: Note a question which is very similar is [Series of the reciprocal of the difference of two squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2043211/602049), except this other one is $4$ times the expression of this one and it asks for a finite limit of $N$ instead of $\infty$. Also, both the other question's & answer's values are off by a factor of $4$.

Comment: @RudyCoburt FYI, a couple of other similar questions here are [Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n+1)(2n-1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3000526/602049) and [Sum of $\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)}$ from $1$ to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467382/602049).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right),
\end{align*}
telescoping to $f(n)=2n-1$ that $f(n+1)=2n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{2 (2 n - 1)} - \frac{1}{2 (2 n + 1)} \ldots
$$
so this is a telescoping series (meaning that each term cancels part of the previous term).  The only term that isn't cancelled in the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ is the first: the sum converges to $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks. Does the last term of a telescoping series (n = ∞) count to the sum as well? I know in this case the last term is 0, but had it been a nonzero number, would the last term count to the sum?

Comment: That would become the $\lim$, not that you plugging in.

Comment: You got to do the partial sum first: $\sum_{n=1}^{N}$ with $N$ fixed, then you got the tail like $-1/(2N+1)$ and this goes to $0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Right, @user284331 is correct ... something like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n - a_{n+1})$ is the limit of the partial sums, which are $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(a_n - a_{n+1}) = a_1 - a_{N+1}$.  So the infinite sum is $a_1 - \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} a_N$ if the limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

Take the $n^{th}$ term of this sequence

$$T_n = \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(2n+1) - (2n-1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$

$$\implies Tn = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

Can you see where this is going?